# how to make a wind quiver plot on the geospatial map using plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, plotly-dash, jupyter-lab

I have a series of the wind dataset with u/v component and try to make it as the quiver (wind vector) plot using plot.ly on the geospatial map. However, I still get troubles to make it happen. Could someone please help me to figure this out?

Following is my code

```
###- This is operating on Jupyter lab with dash extension
###- lon/lat/u/v are 2-D numpy array 

fig = ff.create_quiver(lon,lat,u,v,
                       scale=.25,
                       arrow_scale=.4,
                       name='quiver',
                       line=dict(width=1))

fig['layout'].update(title='Quiver Plot')
fig['layout'].update(geo=dict(
        resolution=50,
        scope='usa',
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=True,
        showland=True,
        landcolor="lightgray",
        countrycolor="white" ,
        coastlinecolor="white",
        projection=dict(type='equirectangular'),
        domain = dict(x=[0, 1], y=[ 0, 1])
))

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph-0',
        figure=fig),
])

viewer.show(app)
```

Comment: I basically asked the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053688/how-to-draw-arrows-on-satellite-view-map-with-plotly
did you figure it out?

Comment: I gave up and change back to use WMS service at that moment. Thanks for letting me know there is an update.

Comment: Franke thanks for the update. I was able to draw arrows on my map by finding the tips of the arrow and making a new trace that goes around them. I know it's ridiculous but it works. If you are interested in this I can answer your question and show you the details

Comment: Please!! I would like to see the detail.

Comment: I will as soon as I have a few minutes

Comment: Franke I posted my solution on my post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053688/how-to-draw-arrows-on-satellite-view-map-with-plotly Hope it will help you. AGM seems to work very well

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use annotations on a scattermapbox while retaining the geo position of the arrows.
[See my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053688/how-to-draw-arrows-on-satellite-view-map-with-plotly) on how to find the arrow points and add them to the map as traces.
If you have several traces, even 40-50 traces or arrows, performances will plummet.
This is a known issue with plotly unfortunately which, I think, makes it basically useless.

You can look into other map APIs like google maps and apple maps. I tested google maps in a angular app and performance are great.